# Docker desktop k8s config file similar to Kind conf

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop, persistent-volumes, kind

I am using kind kubernetes cluster on my Mac and I created it using a config file with mounts as shown [here](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/#extra-mounts)

The pain here is I have to load all images already on my machine pulled using docker pull from my company's docker registry i.e. artifactory. Could I use Docker Desktop and not have to load images separately using kind load docker-image ${imageTag} and still mount volumes into Docker Desktop kubernetes cluster? Where is even the config file to create the cluster in Docker Desktop?

Solving this will hugely help!

Comment: Hi Madhuri, can you clarify if the main requirement is to use a mount (e.g. because a Kubernetes Pod needs to access local files stored on your Mac), or to use KinD (e.g. because you need to simulate a multi-node cluster), or both? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Jerome, The requirement is to use a mount so the startup scripts and env files are available for mounting to nodes in the cluster when the pods start. multi-node cluster is not a requirement but nice to have.

Comment: @jpetazzo any comments?

Comment: I just got it work on Windows, but it looks like Mac will be different. I don't have a Mac machine to try it out, but I found the following StackOverflow question, which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951356/where-is-kubernetes-storage-location-of-a-persistent-volume-on-docker-desktop-fo